# Flutter cannot show JSON image on ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I am parsing the informations like texts or titles without any problem but when I try to show a JSON image in ListTile I am getting this error on emulator: Invalid argument, No host specified in URL

When I test it in console I can see the URL is correct.

```
     child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Title: ${articles[index].title}',
                      ),
                      subtitle:
                          Text('Category: ${articles[index].category?.name}'),
                      trailing: Image.network('articles[index].imageUrl'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
```

Comment: use only `articles[index].imageUrl` remove ''. '' will consider as string.

Comment: this causes another error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove`` from your code.

can add `!` for getting value from `String?`. Recommended to have a `null` check before using `!`

Solution:

```
Image.network(articles[index].imageUrl!)
```

Comment: this causes another error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Answer (score 0):

You must remove ' ' from path just use Below code in your Image.Network widget refer official documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image) hope it's helpful to you

```
Image.network(articles[index].imageUrl),
```

When you get network image from API no need to add ' '